# TUN/TAP write back to tunnel

Tags: tun

My app is using a TUN say tun0. In the design, my app will receive an UDP which includes an full IP layer, then I will take the IP layer out and then use 'file write' to put them into my own tun0 device, supposedly in design, I should can read the packet out again from tun0.

Now the situation is I can see through tcpdump the package is wrote into the tunnel, but I couldn't read them back.

Something wrong with tunnel setting or route setting?

Thanks in advance

Yang

Answer (score 0):

Your second tun0 is not a FIFO queue.  You may have a problem in your design of how and why your are using the second tun0 device.  Clarify why you are using it and which process should be reading.  The proper approach should flow from that clarification.

If you want to read the data you send into you have some options.

- Connect tun0 to an TCP or UDP echo service when you open it.  This will then send you back the packets you stuff into it.
- Open a listener for the second tun0 to connect to.  Then connect to it and send the packets out that connection.  Read your data from the listener side.
- Open a pipe with two file descriptors.  Write to one descriptor and read from the other.  Pipes are often used for IPC (Inter-Process Communication) when forking children.
- Create a socket and read data from it.  Open the other end of the socket for writing.  Sockets are often used to allow other processes to communicate with a process.  This works well when the calling processes may have a different lifetime than the listening process.
- Create a buffer or queue in memory to store the data.

Comment: En, I'm using a way similar with the second option: During init, I open a file descriptor say tunfd connecting tun0, then put it into epoll to listen any incoming. After I write the IP packet in, supposedly, once I got any signal from epoll, I will go to read the packet out from tun0 by reading tun0. Is the method right?

Comment: By the way, I use same tun0 to write and then read. I guess the packet may loop back to the tun0 rather than be sent out physically.

Comment: Are you sure you are opening a tunnel connection and not a pipe called tun0? If you are really using a network tunnel, you should be setting up an IP connection before using it.

Comment: En. Yes, before using tun0, I binded one IP with it. It's working fine when the packets are coming from outside. The problem is: when I tried to file write a packet to the tun0 device, then read them back by file read, it's not working. strerr(errno) is saying "resource temporary not available". It looks somehow the loop back in tun0 is not working.

Comment: @Yang tun0 is not normally a loopback device. When you write to tun0, the other end should be reading them not you.  I've rewritten my response above.  Just because you can or could use the tun0 as a FIFO does not make it a good idea.

Comment: En. Good point. The reason I need to write the pack into tun0 is there are nattings in my iptables. I need to let the response pack go through the nat table to translate the server address in IP to its original one which my client supposedly wants to connect to. Supposedly, writing back to tun0 can let the pack go through the natting table, isn't?

Comment: @Yang You can send replies back to the client via same connection on tun0.  Using a different connection won't do what you want.  The client's real (or remotely NATed) address is in the incoming connection data.

Comment: More. I binded an IP and an UDP socket with the tun0. The file descriptor to the tun0 is used to read and write the packs, but not the UDP socket binded. I put tun0's file descriptor into epoll. Actaully I can read packages if they are physically from out side to the IP binded with tun0. But when my app writes the packages into the tun0, it doesn't work when trying to read them back.

Comment: @Yang That's the way it is supposed to work. The other end needs to read what you write.

Comment: Better to set rp_filter=2 (loose mode), enough to me.